# Ошибка при подключении к хосту

Tags: python

Выдаёт ошибку, когда подходит очередь клиента писать сообщение. Как это решить?

> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Хост:

```py
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind (('0.0.0.0',5050))
client = [] # Массив где храним адреса клиентов
print ('Start Server')
while 1 :
         data , addres = sock.recvfrom(1024)
         print (addres[0], addres[1])
         if  addres not in client : 
                 client.append(addres)# Если такова клиента нету , то добавить
         for clients in client :
                 if clients == adress : 
                     continue # Не отправлять данные клиенту который их прислал
                 sock.sendto(data,clients)
```

Клиент:

```
import socket
import threading
def read_sok():
     while 1 :
         data = sor.recv(1024)
         print(data.decode('utf-8'))
server = '195.191.79.194', 27015
print("Паша, введи псевдоним.")
alias = input() # Вводим наш псевдоним
sor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sor.bind(('', 0)) # Задаем сокет как клиент
sor.sendto((alias+' Connect to server').encode('utf-8'), server)# Уведомляем сервер о подключении
potok = threading.Thread(target= read_sok)
potok.start()
print("Паша, введи сообщени.")
while 1 :
    mensahe = input()
    sor.sendto(('['+alias+']'+mensahe).encode('utf-8'), server)
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас несколько довольно странных мест. Например (сервер):

```
sock.bind (('0.0.0.0',5050))
```

Вот, что пишется про задание IP адреса на стороне сервера:

> Если в поле host передается пустая строка, это равносильно
>   использованию константы INADDR_ANY, которая соответствует любому
>   адресу. Обычно такой способ адресации используется на стороне сервера,
>   когда создается сокет, принимающий соединения от любых клиентов.

Я думаю, что '0.0.0.0' вовсе **не** эквивалентно *INADDR_ANY*. Поэтому я не понимаю, что будет слушать Ваш сервер.

Клиент:

```
server = '195.191.79.194', 27015
```

Вы кому собираетесь отправлять сообщения?! Ваш сервер должен слушать порт 5050, а передаёте Вы на порт 27015... Это что означает?

Мне кажется, Вам надо сначала чётко разобраться, что же Вы хотите сделать, а уже потом писать программу.